# How to add multiple webpages to a svelte application

Tags: html, svelte

I looked at Sapper and it appears to have been replaced by SvelteKit. Do I need a routing framework or what? I made my app with rollup and added SASS to it.

Comment: your question is not clear, svelte is used to create webpages what do you mean by adding webpage to svelte ?

Comment: For example, if I have localhost:5000 as my main page, I want to have a .svelte file that adds localhost:5000/signup to my website.

Comment: @JoJoYawson created this just now, hired a friend of mine, without SvelteKit: github.com/kokizzu/svelte-mpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a front-end router.

You can use [tinro](https://github.com/AlexxNB/tinro) or [svelte-routing](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing) to create your routes.

here is an example using [tinro](https://github.com/AlexxNB/tinro).

```svelte
<script>
    import {Route} from 'tinro'; 
    import Signup from './Signup.svelte'
</script>

<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/signup">Signup</a>

</nav>

<Route path="/">
    <h1>This is the main page</h1>
</Route>

<Route path="/signup">
    <Signup />
</Route>
```

You can write your `signup` markup in `Signup.svelte`

Don't forget to add `--single` to your npm scripts in `package.json` as follows so you can navigate between the pages.

```json
{
  "name": "svelte-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "dev": "rollup -c -w",
    "start": "sirv public --single"
  }
}
```

if you intend to use server side rendering or got complexe backend logic you could read [svelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) documentation.